Does a deque maintain its capacity even if emptied completely?
I wanted to test if a deque<> does free its chunks if it is completely emptied:
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

uint64_t nAllocs = 0, nFrees = 0;

void *operator new( size_t n )
{
    ++nAllocs;
    return malloc( n );
}

void operator delete( void *p )
{
    ++::nFrees;
    free( p );
}

int main()
{
    deque<void *> dq;
    for( size_t i = 100; i--; )
        dq.push_front( nullptr );
    cout << ::nFrees << endl;
    while( !dq.empty() )
        dq.pop_back();
    cout << ::nFrees << endl;
    dq.shrink_to_fit();
    cout << ::nFrees << endl;
}

Interestingly there are no additional frees before I call shrink_to_fit. Is this mandated by the standard ? And are the freed chunks of the deque<> attached to the other end to speed up further appends at the front ?
I don't ask for the suggested alternative question when there's reallocation. But how the capacity is handled and how memory is recycled internally.

This question is similar to: When does std::deque need reallocation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Did you try with a queue with more elements? (e.g. 100 elements). I have the impression that it will only free complete blocks.

“It is a non-binding request to reduce the memory usage without changing the size of the sequence. It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled.
All iterators (including the end() iterator) and references are invalidated.“ Also, see the example in cppreference, shrink_to_fit, it does it with more elements to make sure you see the deallocations.

It is implementation dependent. I am using gcc 12.2.1, and added some more debugging. Your results may be different.
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

uint64_t nAllocs = 0, nFrees = 0;

void *operator new( size_t n )
{
    ++nAllocs;
    void * ptr = malloc( n );

    printf("new %d: %p\n", n, ptr);
    return ptr;
}

void operator delete( void *p )
{
    printf("delete %p\n", p);
    ++::nFrees;
    free( p );
}

int main()
{
    cout << "constructor:\n";
    deque<void *> dq;

    cout << "\npush front\n";
    for( size_t i = 100; i--; )
        dq.push_front( nullptr );
    cout << "nAllocs: " << nAllocs << " nFrees: "<< ::nFrees << endl;

    cout << "\npop back\n";
    while( !dq.empty() )
        dq.pop_back();
    cout << "nAllocs: " << nAllocs << " nFrees: "<< ::nFrees << endl;

    cout <<  "\nshrink to fit\n";
    dq.shrink_to_fit();
    cout << "nAllocs: " << nAllocs << " nFrees: "<< ::nFrees << endl;

    cout << "\ndestructor\n";
}

With the output:
constructor:
new 64: 0x10f02c0
new 512: 0x10f0310

push front
new 512: 0x10f0520
new 512: 0x10f0730
nAllocs: 4 nFrees: 0

pop back
delete 0x10f0310
delete 0x10f0520
nAllocs: 4 nFrees: 2

shrink to fit
new 64: 0x10f0940
new 512: 0x10f0520
delete 0x10f0730
delete 0x10f02c0
nAllocs: 6 nFrees: 4

destructor
delete 0x10f0520
delete 0x10f0940

To me it looks like it is keeping at least one internal buffer of 512 bytes around to put queue entries in.  The 64 byte buffer is probably some sort of index to the buffers.


But how the capacity is handled and how memory is recycled internally.

It's an implementation detail, so the question is only meaningful once you specify an implementation you're interested in.
Once you do that, you can just read the source.
Note that caching could occur either in std::deque or std::allocator (or of course in neither).

The standard does not specify when a deque should release unused space, so memory management depends on the specific implementation.
The following two links provide detailed explanations on this topic:
Inside STL: The deque, design
Inside STL: The deque, implementation
Raymond Chen's blog contains a wealth of useful knowledge, and many answers to questions can be found there. However, due to a website redesign, comments before 2019 have disappeared. This link used to be an archive of the blog that preserved past comments. Unfortunately, the archive recently disappeared, and the capture on the Wayback Machine are incomplete. (If anyone knows of other archives that have preserved the past comments, please let me know.)
By the way, because the blocks implemented by MSVC are only 16 bytes, storing small elements will consume 2.5 times the space. When will the next ABI break finally come...

I think the 16+ byte chunks aren't actually a problem since with MSVC the free chunks  are only given back to the allocator if you do a shrink_to_fit(). As multiple elements can be stored in a Chunk there's 9 / 16 * 100% = 56% maximum blend.

@EdisonvonMyosotis
I don't quite understand the meaning of "As multiple elements can be stored in a Chunk there's 9 / 16 * 100% = 56% maximum blend."
But I know MSVC deque has poor space efficiency (consuming 2.5 times the memory of a vector with the same number of small elements).

Up to 8 byte you can store multiple elements in the chunk. With 9 bytes there's as most blend as possible in the chunk.

@EdisonvonMyosotis
What does the word "blend" mean? (Please forgive me if this is a silly question; my English isn't very good.) And why do you think the 16+ byte chunks aren't actually a problem?
